# Database for Windows Phone 7

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, sqlite

I'm looking to release a really simple application for windows Phone 7. Unfortunately, My Apps need to store some data in the device. say a Database.

My colleague found one SQLite library - http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2010/03/sqlite-for-wp-7-series-proof-of-concept.html

But How about Linq to SQL or EF for Windows Phone 7. Any Library for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perst [works well](http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2010/06/07/perst-a-database-for-windows-phone-7-silverlight.aspx) under Windows 7

Comment: + 1 . This is very interesting. I didn't realize of Perst before. will run comparison in Dev vs Performance with Winphone7DB.

Comment: ok, after testing. I am going with Perst. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, I hope you would have built apps with Perst. Now what do you think about it? Do you still think this is better than other options like sqlite?

Answer (score 2):

In the initial release of Windows Phone 7 you have no SQL Server Compact or similar. Because no user app can call P/Invoke no other mobile/compact database will work.

To store content you have to use Isolated Storage and build something with this. See this: http://winphone7db.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1 very nice. thank you. I see the test project provide a sample too. will check it out and build sample app with it.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite worked fine for me.  Complex joins are slower, but that I bet that would be true for any database.  I have over 50MB of data in case you are wondering.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx).

Info about [compact and linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546181.aspx)

Comment: SQL Compact is not an option in the first release of Windows Phone

Comment: new CE is coming out - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx ,try to validate it. will get back to this post.

Comment: "That is something we are looking to enable as well in the future. Not there just yet though :-)" ScottGu said.