# Local Sql database support for Windows phone 7

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

I would like to develop for Windows Phone 7 but the lack of database support still blocks me. Has anyone found a good library, stack to use for accessing local database from WinPhone7?
Can you post links/examples of good practices to select/insert data in DB from a WinPhone7 application?

Thanks in advance !
c.

[edited] any updates available?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147078/database-for-windows-phone-7

Comment: any of these are no-SQL? Hate SQL...

Comment: Mango brings integrated SQL....

Comment: Well, Mango brings Sql without the Sql... Queries will be Linq only, no T-Sql allowed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are lots of options:

[WinPhone7Db](http://winphone7db.codeplex.com/)
[Perst](http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2010/06/07/perst-a-database-for-windows-phone-7-silverlight.aspx)
[SQLite](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2010/03/sqlite-for-wp-7-series-proof-of-concept.html) (and [here](http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/))
[siaqodb](http://siaqodb.com/?p=202)
[db4o](http://developer.db4o.com/Platforms/dotNET/WindowsPhone.aspx)
[Ninja Database Pro](http://www.kellermansoftware.com/p-43-ninja-database-pro.aspx)
[Rapid Repository](http://rapidrepository.codeplex.com/)
[Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com)
[Effiproz](http://www.effiproz.com/)
SQL Compact Edition will be coming in the "Mango" update - due later this year

Comment: did anyone tried db4o? is it good to use?

Comment: Sterling is also a good one and the author is very active in the forum. http://sterling.codeplex.com/

Comment: I use http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/ and I'm very satisifed with it

Comment: I used Perst, very satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [winphone7db](http://winphone7db.codeplex.com/).
This project implements a Isolated Storage (IsolatedStorage) based database for Windows Phone 7. The database consists of table object, each one supporting any number of columns.

Or you can store data on the internet and use webservices.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to use Microsoft's SQL CE with the upcoming tools update due out in May. When end users will have Mango is another story though :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a local database coming in Windows Phone 7.1 / Mango - take a look at the MSDN pre-release documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

You'll need to use Linq to SQL and the databases are still bound  to individual isolated application storage contexts, but otherwise should be as you expect =)