# windows phone 7 database

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone 7 app which will need some basic database functionality.  I came across the following projects on codeplex.  Has anyone tried any of these projects and can help me decide to choose one, please?

http://rapidrepository.codeplex.com/

http://winphone7db.codeplex.com/

Pratik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use SQLite since you can design the database ahead of time using standard SQL commands.  It works pretty well on the phone.

I've written a quick start guide here: http://wirebear.com/blog/2010/11/12/using-sqlite-in-your-wp7-app

> **UPDATE:**
>   This was a valid solution **pre-Mango** but it is NOT what I would recommend now and it is not what we are doing. With Mango Microsoft has given new ways to use SQL CE with LINQ to SQL and is the better way to have a database in your app. A good guide to getting started can be found here: http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/30/31-days-of-mango-day-30-local-database/

Answer (score 1):

There also are other databases available for the phone (see [Local Sql database support for Windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7)).

What's best for you will depend on your requirements:
Do you need anything in particular? transactions? relations or objects?
What's most important? reliability, performance, etc.?