# What is a viable local database for Windows Phone 7 right now?

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

I was wondering what is a viable database solution for local storage on Windows Phone 7 right now. Using search I stumbled upon these 2 threads but they are over a few months old. I was wondering if there are some new development in databases for WP7. And I didn't found any reviews about the databases mentioned in the links below.

- [windows phone 7 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139615/windows-phone-7-database)
- [Local Sql database support for Windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7)

My requirements are:

- It should be free for commercial use
- Saving/updating a record should only save the actual record and not the entire database (unlike WinPhone7 DB)
- Able to fast query on a table with ~1000 records using LINQ.
- Should also work in simulator

---

**EDIT:**
Just tried Sterling using a simple test app: It looks good, but I have 2 issues.

1. Creating 1000 records takes 30 seconds using `db.Save(myPerson)`. Person is a simple class with 5 properties.
   Then I discovered there is a `db.SaveAsync<Person>(IList)` method. This is fine because it doesn't block the current thread anymore.
   **BUT** my question is: Is it save to call `db.Flush()` immediately and do a query on the currently saving IList? (because it takes up to 30 seconds to save the records in synchronous mode). Or do I have to wait until the BackgroundWorker has finished saving?
2. Query these 1000 records with LINQ and a where clause the first time takes up to 14 sec to load into memory.
   Is there a way to speed this up?

Here are some benchmark results: (Unit tests was executed on a HTC Trophy)

```
-----------------------------
purging: 7,59 sec
creating 1000 records: 0,006 sec
saving 1000 records: 32,374 sec
flushing 1000 records: 0,07 sec
-----------------------------
//async
creating 1000 records: 0,04 sec
saving 1000 records: 0,004 sec
flushing 1000 records: 0 sec
-----------------------------
//get all keys 
persons list count = 1000 (0,007)
-----------------------------
//get all persons with a where clause 
persons list with query count = 26 (14,241)
-----------------------------
//update 1 property of 1 record + save
persons list with query count = 26 (0,003s)
db saved (0,072s)
```

Comment: I see there's two close votes on premise of being subjective/argumentative. Changing the wording "what is the best" to "what is a viable" should address this... if Buju doesn't mind this wording for his question?

Comment: By the way, you should download the latest version. There was an issue with the isolated storage provider, it is far faster now.

Comment: thx, but we are using Sqlite now. At the time of testing non of the object based databases was practicable for us. So the only solution left was Sqlite and it had the performance we needed.

Comment: Could you tell me how you got Sqlite up and running?

Comment: i'm using this: http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Buju: do you have any updates on your experiences with sqlite? it seems that there hasn't been an update for months... thanks

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take a look at Sterling - it should address most of your concerns and is very flexible.

http://sterling.codeplex.com/

(Full disclosure: my project)

Comment: +1 Sterling has been around since the early days and Jeremy's been active supporting it.

Comment: I just tried Sterling and found 2 issues. I updated my original post.

Comment: There have been major performance updates recently - were using the 0.9 release or the latest source branch? Can you pull down the latest and post your perf there? It will likely take several seconds to serialize 1000 objects on the phone, even if you were using just straight serialization - however, 30 seconds seems long and the query should be faster. I want to make sure I know the version you are working with before I do more troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

try [Siaqodb](http://siaqodb.com) is commercial project and as difference from Sterling, not serialize objects and keep all in memory for query.Siaqodb can be queried by LINQ provider which efficiently can pull from database even only fields values without create any objects in memory, or load/construct only objects that was requested.

Answer (score 0):

[Perst](http://www.mcobject.com/perst) is free for non-commercial use.

Comment: sry, i mean free for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try Ninja Database Pro.  It looks like it has more features than Sterling.

http://www.kellermansoftware.com/p-43-ninja-database-pro.aspx

Comment: I sent them an email to correct their comparison chart as they indicated Sterling didn't support several features it actually does. Looks like they just removed Sterling from the comparison. Key things Sterling doesn't have: bulk & cascading delete, zero config/auto-table, support outside of Silverlight. However, I don't believe Ninja supports keys and indexes for fast querying and indexing using LINQ without having to deserialize the entire underlying object.

Comment: Jeremy, It actually does support doing LINQ against indexes. Only the objects that meet the index are deserialized:

//Get a list of persons based on the name
var gregQuery = db.CreateIndexQuery<Person>("Name", "Greg");
 
foreach (var person in gregQuery)
{
 Console.WriteLine(person.PersonId);
}