# Using a database in a WP7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7

My project is a receipter {for WP7}.

In this project, how can I use a database and which database should I use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [windows phone 7 database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139615/windows-phone-7-database)

Answer (score 1):

We use SQLite since you can design the database ahead of time using standard SQL commands.  It works pretty well on the phone.

I've written a quick start guide here: http://wirebear.com/blog/2010/11/12/using-sqlite-in-your-wp7-app

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use database in your project.

Look at http://sterling.codeplex.com/ - it looks useful for you. This project has very simple and understandable tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of database options avaialble for Windows Phone 7.

See the known supported list inthe anser to the question: [Local Sql database support for Windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7/3812090#3812090)

Answer (score 0):

One point, as mentioned at Mix, the tool set coming out next month for the mango update will have the build in SqlServer on the phone. If you can afford to wait a bit. But, at the very least you might want to architect it so you can switch when Mango comes out.