# IS there any way to use database in Windows Phone 7.0 application?

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

As I Know windows phone 7.0 not support SQL CE. Is there any way to work with DataBase on windows phone 7.0 or any free tool? Please help me out thank you.

Comment: It has been aked dozens of times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local Sql database support for Windows phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7)

Comment: also a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139615/windows-phone-7-database)

Answer (score 3):

You can try [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org). Its pretty good, standalone and fast. Above all it has [.NET wrappers](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) available.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a list of available/supported databases at: [Local Sql database support for Windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7/3812090#3812090)

Answer (score 2):

I think the new Mango tools (7.1) support SQL CE and Linq.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637516(v=vs.92).aspx for more details on the 7.1 release.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sqlite](http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/) or [Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com/).