# Working With Database In Windows Phone

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

I am a absolute beginner in Windows Phone Development with a basic idea in C# & Silverlight . I am building an application which will require some basic database functionality . Then , I discovered that SQL Server is not compatible with Windows Phone Development ! Then I also found that no local database is not gonna work for WP . What a mess ! I used SQLite in Android . Now anybody just tell me I can use SQLite in Windows Phone . & Show me the way . If not , How can I store data in a database ? Help Please .Thanks in advance .

Comment: Btw , What is SQL CE ? How can i use that stuff in my app ?

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139615/windows-phone-7-database

Comment: `Then I also found that no local database is not gonna work for WP` wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do you need a database? If you need to store basic app configuration materials, Windows Phone has local storage which will work for this.

If you really need database (to store relational data, or other database functionality) then you have a couple of choices:

Windows phone 7.5 (code name mango) has support for SQL CE, which is an optimized version of MS Sql Server for mobile devices.

http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/07/21/using-sql-ce-on-wp7-mango-getting-started.aspx

If you need to target versions earlier than Mango, [SterlingDB](http://sterling.codeplex.com/) is a good alternative.

There are a number of articles on the web dedicated to getting you started with this.

Answer (score 0):

Did yoy try the CS database.. I have connected my sqlite db using vici cool storage. try to have a look on it.

http://viciproject.com/wiki/projects/coolstorage/home

Add your db to your windows phone project keep it as content.And this code:

string fn = "XXXZZ.db.sqlite";

```
        StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(fn, UriKind.Relative));

        IsolatedStorageFile iStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        if (!iStorage.FileExists(fn))
        {
            using (var outputStream = iStorage.OpenFile(fn, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];

                for (; ; )
                {
                    int read = sr.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    if (read <= 0)
                        break;

                    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);

                }
            }
        }
        CSConfig.SetDB(fn);
```

This code connects your db to your project as isolated storage. and you can retrieve the values from the DB using query in an array.

DATA[] result = CSDatabase.RunQuery("SELECT name,age FROM DATA");

Kindly download and add the vici cool storage dll to the reference..

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [C# Sqlite for WP7 on codeplex](http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/). It has downloads, documentation and samples.