# How to access local db in my application?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to Windows Phone 7 development. How to access local db in through my application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working With Database In Windows Phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282261/working-with-database-in-windows-phone)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to save to isolated storage:

```
            var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
            if (settings.Contains("Bell"))
            {
                settings["Bell"] = newBell;
            }
            else
            {
                settings.Add("Bell", newBell);
            }
            settings.Save();
```

To read again from isolated storage:

```
            var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
            if (settings.Contains("Bell"))
            {
                newBell = (string)settings["Bell"];
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay..Please let me know how to use sqlite in WP7..Thanks again.