# Windows Phone 7 - Sql Compact Alternatives?

Tags: windows-phone-7

From what I've read so far, Windows Phone 7 does not support a Sql Compact database for local storage.

What are you using for local storage for times when the phone has no service?  Sure, I can read/write to an xml file or something similar, but if anyone has any suggestions for something that feels a little more "database-like" I'd love to hear them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local Sql database support for Windows phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Sterling DB](http://sterling.codeplex.com/) or [winphone7db](http://winphone7db.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Tther are more options than this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7 for a bigger list