# DLL is not supporting in windows 7 phone application using visual studio 2010

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, dll, windows-phone-7

If I add any dll (like sqllite3.dll, sqlliteclient.dll) I get the below message:

> Reference cannot be added to l because it was not built using the Windows Phone runtime. Windows Phone projects will work only with Windows Phone assemblies.

I could really do with a clean slate to start with that. Kindly provide simple database connection using database with reference dll.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 7 - Sql Compact Alternatives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220860/windows-phone-7-sql-compact-alternatives)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run SQLite in Windows Phone 7, since it cannot run native code.

Instead, [use a C# implementation](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2010/07/wp7-sqliteclient-with-transaction.html).

Comment: The answer in this question contains links to several other Sql implementations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 1):

you can also use SterlingDB based on top of isolated storage, with linq support:

http://sterling.codeplex.com/