# web service or web access in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i have to know about
1)How to insert , delete, update a value in LINQ to SQL?
2)How to display the all rows and column values in kist box or other controls in windows phone?

Comment: these are 2 very different questions. Please ask them separetely to get better answers

Comment: Your question title doesn't correspond to the body of your question either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq2Sql is not supported on the phone. It may be in the future when SQL CE is supported.

A list of currenlty supported databases on the phone can be found at [Local Sql database support for Windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7/3812090#3812090)

There are lots of ways that you can display data in a list or grid. However, with a portrait orientation and a relatively small amount of screen real estate, tables  (grids) are seldom a good way of displaying data. If you can provide more detail about the data you wish to display we may be able to advise more appropriately.

For an example of displaying data in a listbox using a viewmodel and databinding can be seen in the default code which is included when you create a new "Windows Phone Databound Application".