# Connecting and manuplating data on an access database?

Tags: database, ms-access, windows-phone-7, mobile

I'm working on my thesis project with Windows Phone 7. I'm developing an application requires store data in a database, my thesis supervisor said an Microsoft Access database is enough for this step, because I'm newbie at developing applications for Windows Phone 7.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 7 doesn't support MS Access.

For a list of databases which are supported on WP7 see [Local Sql database support for Windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7/3812090#3812090)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 7 can't have direct access to a database since standard DB connection drivers are not compatible with this platform. What you can do is built a multi-layered project, where there is a web service (easily built with WCF) that connects your Windows Phone 7 application to a local (or remote) database.

You could send request to the web service and it will send those to the database. The same service can send the response back to the app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot remember the details, but I saw a fairly recent presentation on integrating Sharepoint, Access and the Windows phone.

EDIT

I just found this video:

http://pocketnow.com/windows-phone/sharepoint-office-2010-on-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 0):

For access 2010, IT allows one to build web databases. You need SharePoint (Enterprise), and access 2010. You also be able to use Office 365 and skydrive (not out yet).

The resulting access web database can thus be used on the windows 7 phone with the browser. In fact, I have a windows 7 phone and have tested my access applications on it.

In the following video, note how at the half way point, I swtich to using and running the access application in a web browser.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI