# Searching a collection of text files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, search, windows-phone-7

I am making a simple application. Part of this lets the user make entries in a virtual journal. It is written in C# for Windows Phone.

How would I search these files from a text box?

The entries in the journal are all stored in a file folder in IsolatedStorage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the WP7 platform will be limiting what services you can use (e.g. Windows Indexing Service) (I don't know, I never developed for the platform).

I think your best bet would be not to store the journal entries in files, but in a database (assuming a database is available for WP7 at the moment.. I think I've read some open source databases have been ported) and using the built in search facilities of the database.

You can always generate the journal entry as a file on the fly if the user wants to export it.

Comment: I found one database (http://winphone7db.codeplex.com/). I haven't tried it yet, but previous downloads from this website have been useful, so I think it will work. Anyway, thanks for the recommendation to use databases- I think having just text files was getting too complicated anyway.

Comment: There are lots of database options. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7/3812090#3812090

Answer (score 0):

you can also consider Sterling DB:

http://sterling.codeplex.com/

which supports LINQ queries and working with objects in type safe manner.

Basically you have to work with Isolated Storage anyway, just have to choose the right form.

Comment: Thanks. Although I'm not really sure how to convert my existing code to use a database. Do you know of any tutorials?

Comment: When you download it from Codeplex, there is a sample project along with the main source.

Comment: When I downloaded it and opened the example, it asked me for credentials to connect to Team Foundation Server. How do I get around this or get a username and password?

Comment: just cancel the dialog and choos permanently remove the source control