# WP7 Data Storage-- lots of data

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am going to be creating a WP7 app that needs to store a decent amount of data. Specifically, blocks of text (short article length), and more than 50-500 at any one time.

I am a PHP guy, so I would use MySQL if I were doing this on a server, so is there an equivalent database system or data storage system for WP7 that can handle this amount of text? Would IsolatedStorage be ok for this, or do I have to use something else?

It doesn't have to be SQL, just something that can handle lots of data. I just used MySQL as an example because it would be (my) ideal choice if this were a server.

Comment: MS SQL would be good for you? ...And by the way, you can use MySQL even on a Windows platform (server side)

Comment: I did a quick search and can't find anything about MS SQL for WP7. Do you have a link? Btw, it doesn't have to be SQL, it just has to be able to handle lots of data...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7

Comment: Ah, SQLite is in there-- perfect. Thanks! If you post something as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @Andrew, sorry, I misunderstood your question first. I thought you need a db on server side...

Comment: @Andrew, you can vote up a comment, too :)

Comment: @Andrew_M This is a duplicate question, so maybe it is best to just close it? :)

Comment: Sure, I'll go ahead and do that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently lots of databases which support Windows Phone 7. See the list at: [Local Sql database support for Windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7/3812090#3812090)

You don't have to use a database though if flat files would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [LINQ To XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) and storing the XML files in isolated storage. The technology is great. It has intellisense in VS and the syntax is similar to SQL so you should be able to pick it up easily. Ive used this for a similar scenario like yours and the performance was good.

Here is a link to a sample to help you get started:

[LINQ TO XML Sample](http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/petevickers/archive/2010/12/06/windows-phone-7-linq-to-xml-corruption.aspx)

The nice thing is once you learn this you can use it when reading web services, writing to xml files, updating etc. Let me know if this helps.

**Update:** With mango we now have access to SQL Server Compact. All the info is at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).