# Using databases in Windows Phone 7 applications

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm new to the windows phone 7 application project. I dont know how to use the database in windows phone 7. Would u please help me for this one?

Comment: can you provide some detail or specifics? What data base do you need? Have you tried [searching](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+phone+7+database&sitesearch=stackoverflow.com/questions&qscrl=1)

Comment: how to connect the sqlite database to wp7.actually i dont know which database i have to ues this one.would u pls send any sample examples.........

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware you cannot use any form of a MS SQL database at the moment - you have to use [IsolatedStorage](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage). However, I believe there is an update coming later in the year codenamed 'mango' that will introduce the ability to use a SQL CE database.

I have found this though which demonstrates how to use SQLite: http://www.wirebear.com/blog/2010/11/12/using-sqlite-in-your-wp7-app

Comment: Yes, if you truly need a local DB, wait for the update that includes SQL CE.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the Sterling database. Lightweight, supports tombstoning and great support. Install using NuGet or download [here](http://sterling.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of database options for Windows Phone 7. See [Local Sql database support for Windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7/3812090#3812090)