# What are the major differences between developing for Windows Phone 7 and developing for Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

I have many years of experience with Windows Mobile, but I have not yet done anything with Windows Phone 7.

I'm interested in knowing what the major differences are between developing for the two platforms.  I know they both use C# and .NET, but that's about it.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest different is that the default application platform for .NET on Windows Mobile is .NET Compact Framework (.NET 3.5 SP1) and a "compact" version Windows Forms.  For Windows Phone 7, you'll still be dealing with a compact version of the .NET framework, but the main application platform is Silverlight rather than Windows Forms.  Silverlight is based on the newer presentation framework WPF.

The other big difference is the OS/platform APIs.  Windows Mobile has okay support for hardware APIs, but the OS itself and the hardware tended to be really clunky and hard to work with, from both a developer's and user's perspective.  The network connection manager on Windows Mobile is one of the most miserable APIs I've worked with lately.  The Windows Phone 7 hardware overall is way nicer, and I would hope that the platform APIs are a little cleaner and less clunky, but I haven't worked with it enough to say at this point.

Comment: Amen about the network connection manager in Windows Mobile - *huge* POS. However, if you think the OS and the hardware in WM are hard to work with, you should try BlackBerry development. :)

Comment: Ha ha, so true.  I did one foray into Blackberry development, and when I found out that the "standard" way to do development was to use their home-grown, super crappy Blackberry Java IDE, I decided that it wasn't worth it.  Maybe that is different now though, but I doubt it.

Comment: No, nowadays the sane people use Eclipse for BB development. Er, I mean the *truly* sane people use Eclipse for Android development. I tried using the BB IDE for about 10 seconds before my eyeballs burst.

Answer (score 2):

Another major difference is that for WinMo you use Studio 2008, for Phone you use Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest change is the use of SilverLight now.

Take a look at this...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402529(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working in Windows Mobile and was quite excited about Windows Phone 7 but unfortunately it seems to be almost useless for full-on business apps because I believe that you can't have a local sql database running on the device :(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7/3812090#3812090