# SqlAnywhere and windows phone 7 connectivity?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i am new to windows phone 7 development , i wish to like to know, how can i create SQLANYWHERE database in my windows phone 7 application? and also the connectivity of windows phone 7 with SQLANYWHERE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there no SQL database support on the Windows Phone 7 platform. The new Windows Phone 7 Mango SDK does provide a native database using [LINQ-to-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). There are various third party solutions to SQLite, such as http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/ which I've used but find the performance leaves a lot to be desired. If that doesn't suit you, check out [MattLacey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811693/local-sql-database-support-for-windows-phone-7/3812090#3812090) to a similar SO question.

Cheers,
Al.