# Use built-in local database or Isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

Local database is now built into Windows Phone 7.5 Mango. I'm considering a scenario of storing a few unrelated collections with data. Using the local database is pretty straightforward, while using Isolated storage requires a bit more custom development. There are also some alternative solutions like FileDb, mentioned in a pre-mango discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6954250/346995

What would be the best solution of local database/Isolated storage with regards to simplicity and performance? Would local database fit most scenarios?

Comment: Isolated storage will be simple and more efficient. You can easily serialize your object using DataContracts and a binary serializer.

Comment: The db uses isolated storage too.  Check out SterlingDB simple and powerfull.

Comment: Part of why am posting this question is that many developers are used to handling databases, while there is a certain treshold dealing with file storage and serialization choices/issues. Given that many developers would choose the built-in database solution, is there any major reasons why they should not go down this path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you are going to be storing relational data (and it sounds like you aren't) I would suggest using the IsoStore. It isn't really that difficult to use.

Now, as far as performance. Reading the disk on the phone is not going to be fast. That being said, any solution you use is going to be saved to disk in the end; so I don't think you will notice much of a difference if you go with DB or IsoStore.

[Isolated Storage Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
[Isolated Storage Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769544%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
[31 Days of Mango: Isolated Storage](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/)
[Using Isolated Storage in Windows Phone 7](http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/09/03/Using-Isolated-Storage-on-Windows-Phone-7.aspx)