# How to manage a local database in isolated storage?

Tags: c#, .net, database, windows-phone-7

I read about [local database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and [isolated storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416058/use-built-in-local-database-or-isolated-storage) for Windows Phone 7. Is this feature only present in Windows Phone 7? Or could I also use it in Desktop applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows phone 7 contains tools which make using a local database easier for phone applications.

This is mainly because databases are such an important feature that, if handled wrongly, could affect the operation of the device and the fluid, speedy nature of the UI.

It's possible to use this same kind of thing on Desktop applications but in a less managed way.

Here are some pages to have a read of:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233817.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx

Hope they help.